When power is turned on, pull-down 50K potentiometer to 0 for a few seconds
Potentiometer is used as a voltage-divider type volume control. I'm thinking of using something like a ne555 timer, a transistor, and a pull-down resistor. Just not sure how i'd connect this all together. Any help/ideas?
In this particular case, the VCC is 12 volts from a separate power supply + voltage regulator, the signal flowing through the pot is ~= +5V biased audio signal of maybe a few volts peak-to-peak maximum, but i'd like a solution that would also work in other (audio/line-level) applications.

Please update your question with more details and a schematic of what you have now.  Signal amplitude and frequency range, any DC bias on the signal, available power supply (supplies) for the circuit?  Depending on the answers, this might be a simple as 2 R's, 1 C, and 1 transistor.

Absent more information, this is a wild guess at a first pass at a solution.
R1-C1 form the mute timer.  As C1 charges up, the voltage at the gate goes toward GND.  At around 2 V the FET starts to turn off, unmuting the audio.  The time this takes is directly dependent on the (unknown) value of Vcc.
R2 assures that C1 is discharged in a reasonable time.  If Vcc is disconnected (as opposed to turned off), the unmute voltage could sit on C1 for hours.  This would prevent muting action when Vcc is restored.  R2 provides a discharge path that is independent of the power source off-state impedance.
UPDATE:
Now that the OP has said there is a DC bias on the audio signal, the circuit can be adapted for this, with a consequence.
Add a capacitor between the Rx wiper and the Q1 drain.  The capacitor value depends on how much audio you can tolerate leaking through at the low frequencies.  If the audio signal source impedance is very low, then the impedance seen by the FET varies from 0 ohms to 25K.  This resistance plus the capacitor forms a lowpass filter whose cutoff frequency depends on the pot position.
A way around this is to add a resistor in series with the Rx.  If that is 1 K, it attenuates the max audio signal level by only 2%.  If the added capacitor is 15 uF, then the worst case low frequency response will be down by only 1 dB at 20 Hz (-ish).
I'll update the schematic for this.


Here's a mute circuit using a 2SD2704K transistor that will function for typical audio levels. These transistors are unusual for having high (25V) Vebo breakdown.

The 1KΩ series resistor is optional (and could perhaps better be 5kΩ or 10kΩ), but if the source driving the 50kΩ pot is low impedance then the muting would be limited with the volume cranked up all the way, and it could conceivably damage the pot if a very small length of pot element was engaged.
This works with an unbiased AC signal. If your signal is biased wrt ground you probably don't want to shunt it to ground in DC terms so you don't get a huge thump. If you add a large-ish capacitor (eg. 10uF electrolytic) in series with the 2SD2704K collector it will only shunt out the AC component.
